# python change child object and propagate to parent

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have an object "surface" which is stored in a "cell" as a list. You can think of a cube which is made of surfaces. Despite I can change surface properties using the "cell" object, there are times when is more convenient for me to change it directly on the "surface". Is it possible to change a property in "surface" object and then propagate it automatically to the same surface within "cell"? An example:

```
class Surface(object):
     def __init__ (self, color):
         self.color = color


class Cell(object):
     def __init__(self, surfaces)
         self.surface = surfaces

surfaces = []
surfaces.append(Surfaces(color='blue'))
surfaces.append(Surfaces(color='blue'))
surfaces.append(Surfaces(color='blue'))
surfaces.append(Surfaces(color='blue'))
surfaces.append(Surfaces(color='blue'))
surfaces.append(Surfaces(color='blue'))

cell = Cell(surfaces)

surface[0].color = 'red'

print(cell.surface[0].color)
```

> 'red'

When changing the surface color I would like it to be propagated to the same child within the "cell" object. Is this possible?
Appreciate the help!

Comment: You could write a method on `Cell` that changes the colors of all surfaces. That would even fit better into object oriented programming.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking (and if by `surface[0]` you mean `surfaces[0]`), then it should be doing what you want already.